# Save an XML file via UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xml, sdk, uiwebview, nsxmlparser

I have an XML file on a remote server. The user must log in to access this file. Is there away to download the xml page after the user logs into a UIWebview?
Then have NSXMLParser parse the downloaded page?

```
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://se7ensins.com/forums/xml.php"];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathURL];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the NSURL of the XML page that the user would go to in the UIWebView and use:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url
```

Comment: I updated the OP with some code that i've been using. I have a webview. I have the user log in. Then i run the XMLparser initialized with that code.